# MVC 4: How to render view from database string and produce string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Ho to render mvc 4 razor view from database string into view and the final product is converted view to string?

I already able to render view (file) and produce string, but what i need is to render view from string (database).

This is the code that i use to render view (file) to string:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model, string controllerName)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    Type controllerType = Type.GetType(controllerName + "Controller");
    object controller = Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType);
    RouteData rd = new System.Web.Routing.RouteData();
    rd.Values.Add("controller", "Account");
    ((ControllerBase)(controller)).ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(HttpContext, rd, (ControllerBase)controller);
    ControllerContext cc = ((ControllerBase)(controller)).ControllerContext;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(cc, viewName, null);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(cc, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(cc, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

I need to somehow manipulate these code:

```
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(cc, viewName, null);
var viewContext = new ViewContext(cc, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
```

So the code does not try to find view (file) to be rendered, instead of just render string view. example:

```
string view = "This is the view that needs to be rendered! @Model.Name, ....";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult RenderViewToString()
{
    string html = "this is your view string";

    // Push it to a View
    ViewBag.RenderedHtml = html;

    return View();
}
```

Helpful?

link : http://www.codemag.com/article/1312081

Comment: Sorry, but that article basically explaining what i already done in my code, which is to render view (file) to string. And your code i just to display the string as raw string, which i dont want that. I need to render the string first so the engine translate all the helpers (@Html.BeginForm, @Url.Action, etc..) then after translation, it will be outputted as string.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine. By using RazorEngine you can output html from database string instead of a cshtml file